# TortoiseSVN and Mac OS

Tags: macos, svn, tortoise-svn

I'm working with other developers - who are on a Windows environment using TortoiseSVN and I need to be able to work with them from my MAC.

Will the SVN Client SCplugin be able to interface with the windows clients?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Subversion is the key here, not the front-end that sits on top of it.  TortiseSVN and SCPlugin both use Subversion, so you'll be able to integrate with your Windows counterparts just fine.

Comment: Ah I see, so I've got subversion already, and now I've got svnX, but I'm having trouble actually connecting - it's a windows server that has the SVN server on it, so I'm not sure how to connect into it..

Answer (score 2):

Check out **[Cornerstone](http://zennaware.com/cornerstone/)** and **[Versions](http://versionsapp.com/)**. They're two great Subversion clients for Mac that don't rely on the filesystem browser (Finder) for navigating your working copies. Personally, I prefer Cornerstone's interface over Versions, but they're both very capable apps that should work just fine with your Subversion server and Windows/TortoiseSVN developers.

Answer (score 0):

Assembla have a great comparison list of Subversion clients for Mac OSX, with reviews:
http://svn-ref.assembla.com/mac-svn-client-reviews.html

See also on superuser => https://superuser.com/questions/58225/tortoisesvn-for-mac

Comment: Both links are dead. This may be an updated link replacing the first link: https://blog.assembla.com/AssemblaBlog/tabid/12618/bid/84534/Subversion-client-releases-for-Windows-and-Macintosh.aspx